# Finding difficulty to implement Inheritance in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, inheritance

I have 3 UIView classes like 
1)Generic : UIView
2) IPhoneView: Generic
3) IPadView: Generic.

In Generic class i am setting target like below :

```
  //Generic.h class
  @interface Generic : UIView
  {
    id  mTarget;
  }

 -(void)setDelegate:(id)inDelegate;


//Generic.m class
@implementation Generic
-(void)setDelegate:(id)inDelegate
{
     mTarget=inDelegate;
} 
@end
```

This method is calling from controller -

```
//My IPhoneView.h
 #import "Generic.h"

 @interface IPhoneView : Generic

 {

 }
 -(void)initializeUIElements;


    //My IPhoneView.m

    @implementation IPhoneView

    - (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
    {
       self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
       if (self) {
      // Initialization code
       NSLog(@"mTarget value : %@",mTarget);
       }
      return self;
    }
```

IPadView also the same kind of behaviour.

then IPhone and IPad classes are inheriting from Generic class. But i couldn't get the mTarget value in IPhoneView and IPadView classes. Where i am doing wrong? Help me out!!

Comment: Your question is unclear. You don't provide enough detail to help answer the question.

Comment: how is your mTarget declared?

Comment: mTarget value is id value(id  mTarget) defined in .h file @rajesh

Comment: Just edited and provides few more details for the query. please look into it @rmaddy

Comment: The NSLog in `initWithFrame` is always going to give you nil because you haven't set the mTarget yet.

Comment: i already set that value in Generic class, then @interface IPhoneView : Generic like this.

Comment: @Question Is mTarget being set in `Generic`'s `initWithFrame`? That's the only way you'd see something in that NSLog. You haven't posted that code so we don't really know.

Comment: This question is becoming an interesting mystery. My hunch is that the OP thinks mTarget is going to behave like a static ivar even though its not.

Comment: From my controller call like below:                                  - (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    Generic * genericView = [[Generic alloc] init];
    [genericView setDelegate:self];
    genericView = [[IPhoneView alloc]initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
} any thing wrong in my approach @CrimsonChris

Comment: @Question `genericView = [[IPhoneView alloc]initWithFrame:self.view.frame];` is giving you an entirely new object. Why can't you just make an `IPhoneView` and set the delegate on that?

Comment: then how do call my IPhoneView class? is there any other way to achieve my design?

Comment: @Question `IPhoneView *iPhoneView = [[IPhoneView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];  [iPhoneView setDelegate:self];`

Comment: This is again straight froward ryt? if i want to call another UIClass from same controller again i need to set delegate. Instead of that i am setting delegate in one Generic class i want use the same class for all Views.

Comment: @Question What you want doesn't require inheritance to accomplish. Try making your mTarget static. I think that will give you the behavior you are expecting. You should consider reading up on how object oriented programming works.

Comment: @Question, have you looked at my suggestion ?

Answer (score 0):

First you need to create object of **Generic** class in **IPad** or **IPhone** class
and then you can access it by

```
objectOfGenericClass.mTarget
```

Might be helpful in your case:

Comment: IPad: Generic I am assigning like this also need to create object for Generic class? i ll try it once.

Comment: No luck still getting null value in my mTarget object. Thanks for the response @iPatel

Comment: are u checked that mTargate is not null in Generic class ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to expose the mTarget property by putting it in `Generic`'s header file. Subclasses will now "know" that they have this property.

Comment: you mean i need to create @Property for mTarget?

Comment: Make it a property in your header.

Comment: no need of @property when go for inheritance. even ivars are also accessible.

Comment: @rajesh True, I'm still going to encourage the OP to use properties.

Comment: i tried that as well still same result. @CrimsonChris

Comment: @Question Please post the rest of your code. Something is missing, the problem is not in the code you've posted.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should change:

```
  @interface LoginView : UIView
```

with:

```
  @interface LoginView : IPhone
```

**EDIT:**

Your inheritance order should be like this:

```
GenericView<-IPhoneView<-LoginView
```

So, i think you can access `mTarget` in `LoginView`.

Comment: i tried yours suggestion as well but it's not working. Here LoginView is my parent class and IPhone is child class. So it's not possible i guess. Thank you!! NeverHopeless.

Answer (score 0):

As you described, you receive a null target. I think you might override the setter method in your subclasses?

Either way, following worked for me, please check your setter method of the Generic-subclasses and make sure to call the "super-setter"

```
@implementation iPhone
-(void)setDelegate:(id)inDelegate
{
    NSLog(@"My former mTarget: %@",mTarget);
    [super setDelegate:inDelegate];
    NSLog(@"My new mTarget: %@",mTarget);
}

@end
```

Comment: sure, this will work. But my intension is to pass target value from Generic class to different UIView classes.

Comment: So, you have one instance of Generic for several instances of iPhone/iPad Views? Else you don't pass it, but rather inherit the property... In case you want to inherit the property, my answer tells you how you could accomplish it.